# Azure DevOps YAML .Net Core Build Pipeline: Difference between NuGetCommand@2 restore and DotNetCoreCLI@2 restore

Tags: azure-pipelines

All,

Does a MicroSoft Azure DevOps YAML build pipeline which has a DotNetCoreCLI@2 task, with a command of restore, still need a NuGetCommand@2 with a restore?

Reading the info on both do a restore which suggests not but the legacy pipelines I am working with have both so I am trying to understand why that is.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kevins, has my post helped with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the document for [nuget cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=publish%20NuGet%20packages.-,Uses%20NuGet.exe%20and%20works%20with%20.NET%20Framework%20apps.%20For%20.NET%20Core%20and%20.NET%20Standard%20apps%2C%20use%20the%20.NET%20Core%20task.,-If%20your%20code), you could check the reference below.

> Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps.
>
> For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.

And from the task arguments for the two tasks, you could also find the differences.
[Nuget Cli Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#restore) &
[DotNet Cli Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#restore)

**1.Source to use**

For nuget cli task: `restoreSolution` : `The path to the solution, packages.config, or project.json file that references the packages to be restored.`

For .net cli task: `projects`:`The path to the csproj file(s) to use. You can use wildcards (e.g. **/*.csproj)`

**2.Feed to use**

> `dotnet restore` internally uses a version of NuGet.exe that's
> packaged with the .NET Core SDK.  `dotnet restore` can **only**
> restore packages specified in the .NET Core project `.csproj files`.
> If you also have a Microsoft .NET Framework project in your solution
> or use `package.json` to specify your dependencies, use the `NuGet task` to restore those dependencies.

**Some more details for `Dotnet Cli`**

> In .NET Core SDK version 2.0 and newer, packages are restored
> automatically when running other commands such as `dotnet build`,
> `dotnet run`, `dotnet test`, `dotnet publish`, and `dotnet pack`.
> However, you might still need to use the .NET Core task to restore
> packages if you use an authenticated feed.

You could also refer to the D[otnet Cli Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) document for more details.